# cython - initialize 2d c-array

Tags: c, arrays, cython

I would like to create a 2D-array within a `cdef` function with the number of elements in each dimension depending on parameters passed to the function. E.g.:

```
cdef int[:,:] c_volumecheck(int n):

    cdef:
        const int comb = 2**n
        const int nt = n
        int match[comb][nt] 
        size_t i,j

    # initialize values
    for i in range(comb):
        for j in range(n):
            match[i][j] = 0


return match
```

However, assigning to `comb` and `nt` a constant expression does not seem to work as I get the error "Not allowed in a constant expression" in line `int match[comb][nt]`. Manually providing the respective values work (`match[8][3]` for e.g. `n=3`). That is not an option however, as these values change during the program.

The second thing is, that I do not seem to understand how to return this array to another `cdef` or `def` function in the same `.pyx`-script: `int[:,:]` does not seem to correspond to a 2d-array like the one I want to initialize.

Comment: `int[:,:]` is the syntax for a typed memoryview; I"d suggest reading/experimenting with this doc page: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Comment: believe me, I was'nt lazy before I posted my question. But I couldn't find a reference on how to return an array. However, consulting the [c-turorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm), it might be the case that it is not intended to be able to return arrays, as you cannot do so in C as well, only pointers to arrays.

Comment: Can you explain what the calling function is supposed to see?  Is this a purely C level operation, or do you expect to return something useful to Python code (lists, numpy arrays)?

Comment: it is supposed to return to a `def` function in the `pyx'-script. I could probably keep it within a 'cdef' environment. But I will definitly not use the  value outside cython.

Comment: Then is this just standard `c` coding, modified a bit by `cython` syntax?

Comment: yes, that's what i thought.

Comment: Which means that you cannot return an array or memoryview, as it is at the C level. You can pass pointers around however. You can use optimize your code partially by keeping it as a "def" function and return a NumPy array. This will take care of memory allocation, a useful byproduct. For your example: `cdef double[:,:] myarray = np.zeros((2**n, n))` would replace the intialization part of your function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917593/how-to-declare-2d-c-arrays-dynamically-in-cython suggests memoryviews as an alternative to static C arrays.