# Cython compilation error "Not allowed in a constant expression"

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

The following

```
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def boundtest():
     cdef int r=4
     cdef double l[3]
```

works fine. But when I try this:

```
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def boundtest():
     cdef int r=4
     cdef double l[r]
```

I receive the following error:

```
[1/1] Cythonizing test.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def boundtest():
     cdef int r=4
     cdef double l[r]
                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:13:20: Not allowed in a constant expression
```

The decorator was added due to finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917593/how-to-declare-2d-c-arrays-dynamically-in-cython) related stackexchange post and reading the Cython book by Kurt W. Smith. As far as I can tell this should work to tell Cython not to worry about out of bounds errors that may result from having a dynamic indexing variable but for some reason it does not. I have also tried changing boundscheck in the compiler options and globally to no avail.

If it weren't for the Cython documentation claiming to be up to date I would think boundscheck has been depreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The failure has nothing to do with `cython.boundscheck`.

Boundchecking is just checking if you try to access an element of an array that isn't there. For example if you have a size 4 array and try to access element 5 - with `boundscheck(True)` it will give you an Exception, with `boundscheck(False)` it will result in undefined behavior (probably causing a segmentation fault).

The reason for the compilation failure is another: You can't create a static array with a dynamic length! The number of elements need to be known at compile time, that's just something [c](/questions/tagged/c) enforces (I guess).

However you could define `r` to be known at [compile time](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#compile-time-definitions):

```
DEF r=4

cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def boundtest():
    cdef double l[r]
```

You could however simply create a NumPy array and store it in a memoryview variable:

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def boundtest():
    cdef int r=4
    cdef double[:] l = np.empty(r, dtype=np.double)
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much! I wish the OP in the linked post had been a bit more explicit about changing his code to use a memoryview variable.

Comment: @Takoda Cython combines Python and C so it requires a bit of knowledge about both to get it right. Probably it was just "assumed" that you don't create dynamic length arrays using `cdef double l[r]` but only with known constants like `cdef double l[4]`.

Comment: Weird that Cython doesn't support C99 VLAs, but good for them. VLAs are dangerous.