# How to declare lists of lists in cython

Tags: python, cython

I have the following .pyx code:

```
import cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def f(m):
  cdef int n = len(m)/2
  cdef int j, k
  z = [[0]*(n+1) for _ in range(n*(2*n-1))]
  for j in range(1, 2*n):
    for k in range(j):
      z[j*(j-1)/2+k][0] = m[j][k]
  return solve(z, 2*n, 1, [1] + [0]*n, n)


cdef solve(b, int s, int w, g, int n):
  cdef complex h
  cdef int u,v,j,k
  if s == 0:
    return w*g[n]
  c = [b[(j+1)*(j+2)/2+k+2][:] for j in range(1, s-2) for k in range(j)]
  h = solve(c, s-2, -w, g, n)
  e = g[:]
  for u in range(n):
    for v in range(n-u):
      e[u+v+1] += g[u]*b[0][v]
  for j in range(1, s-2):
    for k in range(j):
      for u in range(n):
        for v in range(n-u):
          c[j*(j-1)/2+k][u+v+1] += b[(j+1)*(j+2)/2][u]*b[(k+1)*(k+2)/2+1][v] + b[(k+1)*(k+2)/2][u]*b[(j+1)*(j+2)/2+1][v]
  return h + solve(c, s-2, w, e, n)
```

I don't know how to declare the list of lists in cython to speed the code up.

For example, the variable `m` is a matrix represented as a list of lists of floating point numbers. The variable `z` is a list of lists of floating point numbers too.  What should the line `def f(m)` look like for example?

---

Following the advice in the answer by @DavidW here is my latest version.

```
import cython
import numpy as np
def f(complex[:,:] m):
  cdef int n = len(m)/2
  cdef int j, k
  cdef complex[:,:] z = np.zeros((n*(2*n-1), n+1), dtype = complex)
  for j in range(1, 2*n):
    for k in range(j):
      z[j*(j-1)/2+k, 0] = m[j, k]
  return solve(z, 2*n, 1, [1] + [0]*n, n)


cdef solve(complex[:,:] b, int s, int w, g, int n):
  cdef complex h
  cdef int u,v,j,k
  cdef complex[:,:] c
  if s == 0:
    return w*g[n]
  c = [b[(j+1)*(j+2)/2+k+2][:] for j in range(1, s-2) for k in range(j)]
  print("c stats:", len(c), [len(c[i]) for i in len(c)]) 
  h = solve(c, s-2, -w, g, n)
  e = g[:]
  for u in range(n):
    for v in range(n-u):
      e[u+v+1] = e[u+v+1] + g[u]*b[0][v]
  for j in range(1, s-2):
    for k in range(j):
      for u in range(n):
        for v in range(n-u):
          c[j*(j-1)/2+k][u+v+1] = c[j*(j-1)/2+k][u+v+1] + b[(j+1)*(j+2)/2][u]*b[(k+1)*(k+2)/2+1][v] + b[(k+1)*(k+2)/2][u]*b[(j+1)*(j+2)/2+1][v]
  return h + solve(c, s-2, w, e, n)
```

The main problem now is how to declare c  as it is currently a list of lists.

Answer (score 7):

A list-of-lists is not a structure that can get much speed-up from Cython. The structure you should use is a 2D [typed memoryview](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html):

```
def f(double[:,:] m):
    # ...
```

These are indexed as `m[j,k]` rather than `m[j][k]`. You can pass them any suitably shaped object that exposes the Python buffer protocol. Most frequency this will be a Numpy array.

---

You should also avoid using decorators like `@cython.boundscheck(False)` and `@cython.wraparound(False)` unless you understand what they do and have considered whether they're appropriate for your function. For your current version (where you're using `list`s) they actually do nothing and suggest you have copied them without understanding. They do speed up the indexing of memoryviews (at the cost of some safety).

---

Edit: In terms of initializing `c` you have two options.

1. Initialize a numpy array with the list of lists. This probably isn't hugely quick (but if other steps are slower then it may not matter):

   ```
   c = np.array([b[(j+1)*(j+2)/2+k+2,:] for j in range(1, s-2) for k in range(j)], dtype=complex)
   # note that I've changed the indexing of b slightly
   ```
2. Set up `c` with an appropriately sized `np.zeros` array. Swap the list comprehension for two loops. It isn't 100% obvious to me exactly what this translates to, but it's something like

   ```
   c = np.zeros("some size you'll have to work out",dtype=complex)
   for k in range(j):
       for j in range(1,s-2):
           c["some function of j and k",:] = b["some function of j and k",:]
   ```

You'll also want to replace `len(c)` with `c.shape[0]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go and report back.

Comment: I have made a little progress but am stuck on how to declare `c` now.

Comment: See edit. Option 1 is easy (but not optimized). Option 2 needs a little more thought than I can manage at the moment, but hopefully will give an idea

Comment: Thanks. While I try to work that out, I wanted to define `g` which is a list of length n/2 + 1. I tried `cdef solve(complex[:,:] b, int s, int w, complex g[n/2+1], int n):` but it complains that `[1] + [0]*n` is not the right type (which is what g is set to when solve is first called).

Comment: You want `g[:]` to define it as a 1d array (this doesn't check the size though). You need to pass it a numpy array, not a list. Either make the numpy array from the list, or create one with `np.zeros` and set the first element to 1.

Comment: Thank you. I tried    `c = np.array([b[(j+1)*(j+2)/2+k+2,:] for j in range(1, s-2) for k in range(j)], dtype=complex)` but I get:
`ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 1)` when I run the code.

Comment: I'm puzzled - this works fine for me (with a 5 by 6 input array). Try deleting the `dtype=complex` - it should be able to work it out anyway. Also try replacing `np.array` with `np.vstack`. But those are all guesses because it does work for me.

Comment: This is what I get https://bpaste.net/show/5ec5b2cf5d11 (using python 2)

Comment: It looks like this is happening in some of the recursive calls to `solve` (I only tested a cut-down version with the top level call). I suspect it's actually trying to initialize an empty array, which may or may not be what you want. The simple solution would be to add `ndmin=2` to the call to `array` to force it to be at least 2D. I'd check that the output of this makes sense though (e.g. `print b.shape`)

Answer (score 2):

Like C:

```
cdef float z[100][100]
```

For more detail please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119254/how-to-declare-2d-list-in-cython) link.

Comment: Where does that go in the code? The hafnian function takes m as an argument so you can't put it within that function can you?

Comment: @eleanora you are right, I just wanted to give him an example. tnx.